# Proxy pattern for hardware access in embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

I am reading a book that "Design Patterns for Embedded Systems in C" which is written by Bruce Powel Douglass and ı decided to using Hardware Proxy Pattern for providing encapsulated access to hardware but at some point ı am not sure exactly about impelementing proxy pattern.

For better understanding ı am going to add a scenario:

Let's assume there is a PMIC( power management ic) which can communicate over one of some serial communications.

- We write a pmic.c and pmic.h file which are defined and declarated all variables,function and registers address and values to work with pmic. Let's look at definitions and declarations of some of them:

-in pmic.c-

```
  //included already serial communucation header file like as #include "app_I2C.h"
     uint32_t pmic_read_battery_voltage(){/*Some serial comm function here*/}     
     bool     pmic_Init(){/*Some serial comm function here*/} 
     bool     pmic_configure(uint32_t pmic_cfg){/*Some serial comm function here*/} 
     bool     pmic_set_charge_current(uint8_t charge_curr){/*Some serial comm function here*/}
```

-in pmic.h-

```
     uint32_t pmic_read_battery_voltage();
     bool     pmic_Init();
     bool     pmic_configure(uint32_t pmic_cfg);
     bool     pmic_set_charge_current(uint8_t charge_curr);
```

So you can see that if ı give that pmic.c file directly to client they never access directly hardware side and more than one clients can access this file (maybe another .c files). In fact this is nature of C.

Can we say this pmic.c driver written in proxy pattern because it is hiding hardware side from clients ? ( ı could change basically serial communication side without  clients changing anything on their side)
or
have ı to create new pmicproxy.c file which is including above functions again with having generic struct(like as class ) for access all properties of hardware?

Comment: "hiding hardware side" but "PMIC" is a hardware component, so what are you hiding ?

Comment: I have read this book at some point but I wasn't particularly impressed. _Who cares_ if it is this or that pattern, the purpose of patterns aren't self fulfilment but to be handy tools when solving specific problems. What you describe here is standard rank & file C code, the proper way to design pretty much any module, like for example a driver. If you place an abstration layer on top of the driver so that you may replace the driver when you change hardware, without making other changes to the application, then you have designed a _hardware abstraction layer_ (HAL).

Comment: @GabrielT So, tell me how can ı hide exactly hardware in embedded application? Hiding hardware means is that clients should access all properties of hardware without reading its datasheet - in fact it is HAL- . I think there is a conflicting about HAL and proxy pattern.

Comment: @Lundin ı always create abstraction layer on my projects. At some point , patterns came out  and ı  wonder "Do ı need them?". So, ı decided try one of them and seeing result with my team. Do you think patterns not as good as some programmer says?

Comment: Usually I develop with 3 categories Core(or Application) / Middlewares / Drivers. The engineers in charge of the application just interact with Middlewares files (often in c++). Drivers are all written in C and are hardware specific files. If we change the HW, the application and middlewares remain unchanged

Comment: its better than any book : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @KaruF Actually, intermediately experienced programmers have a tendency to add too many abstraction layers. The rule of thumb is: don't add one unless you need it. This goes for patterns as well. The down side is increased complexity and more complexity = more bugs.

Comment: @GabrielT And Amen to that, I was just about to say as much when I wrote the above comment :) The truly experienced programmers are those who strive for simplicity, not complexity.

Comment: @Lundin ı always say that keep everything simple because of on my ideas about writing some drivers or code, it should usable even for junior development. This why ı am looking for patterns (because ı think it could be standardized my drivers and provides understandable code). But many programmer ı saw they wanna added complexcity to their code like as object-based c, non-understandable patterns. Actually ı can say that we all already have pattern  our pattern which is more easy than proxy etc when we write some drivers to hardwares  (espacially ı am talking about embedded c)

Comment: @Lundin Having met him many years ago, and discussed it (he was son an "experts" panel at a conference), I am pretty sure the purpose of patterns is so methodologists like Bruce can sell more books!

Comment: Patterns are useful when they are widely published and used.  It seems you have to see this book to find out what it is about, and since I don't have it I cannot help, and it will be a somewhat unsuccessful pattern if it is not widely disseminated.  Or it is just wat we always did given a name.  However  what you have presented is so obvious and trivial, I cannot help thinking there is more to it than you think.

Comment: ... For example a common device driver pattern (used in CMSIS for example) is to have a structure or table of function pointers and you "plug-in" your driver by setting the function pointers to point to concrete functions implementing the "interface" promised.  Application layers then invoke the driver via the pointers, allowing default and partial implementations - all the things that will make you wish you were using C++. ;-)  Such a pattern allows for example closed source object code to be used without having to provide symbols with specific names for a linker to resolve.

Comment: @Clifford In my experience design patterns make far more sense on hosted systems, where you might want things like worker thread pools etc. That being said, the more tools the better, even if one of them tools in your tool box is just used every 20th project or something.